# JAXB Marshalling: Creating an empty element with an attribute

Tags: jaxb

I use a JAXB marshaller and I would like to add an empty element with a specific attribute. This is a dummy class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="observation")
public class Observation {

   @XmlAttribute
   public static final String classCode = "OBS";

   @XmlAttribute
   public static final String moodCode = "EVN";

   private String data;

   @XmlElement
   public String getData() {
       return data;
   }

   public void setData(String data) {
       this.data = data;
   }
```

This creates the following XML:

```
<observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
    <data>fsdfsdfd</data>
</observation>
```

Is there any way to add a new element with a specific attribute only (no value at all)? E.g.

```
<observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.31"/>
    <data>fsdfsdfd</data>
</observation>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "TemplateIdType")
public class TemplateIdType {

  @XmlAttribute(name = "root")
  protected String root;

  // getter and setter
}
```

(And you add an element of this class to Observation.)